# Treatment of wound

Tags: dogs, health, injury, first-aid

There's a dog, he's been run over by some vehicle. His leg is most probably broken, his skin has been badly damaged. I'm worried that there's no veterinary hospital nearby, he might develop maggots eventually due to open wound. Please guide me through.

Comment: It sounds like the wound would need to be at the very least cleaned and immobilized, but doing anything like this would probably cause the dog some amount of pain, resulting in him fighting against and/or biting you - particularly if this is not your dog and he doesn't know & trust you. Your best option is to find a vet and not put yourself in unnecessary danger.

Answer (score 2):

Ask a doctor / nurse to treat him. The basic anatomy of a flesh wound and broken leg should be similar enough to a human that the dog does not have to go without any treatment. Put a muzzle on him, try to calm him and hold him still during the procedure.

From experience I know that you can give him Aspirin against pain and infection in a dosage appropriate to his body weight. That is half or a quarter of a pill, depending on his size and weight. Ibuprofen is poisonous for dogs.